# Is SERVFAIL error related to changing of nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

After changing  name servers of recently acquired domain, I receive this SERVFAIL error running `dig` on the domain name. GoDaddy, where I buy domain name, says it's not their fault because the WHOIS records update. Company where I point domain (Amazon) also take no responsibility.

```
->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id:
```

This is my question: Is SERVFAIL error related to changing of name servers? (i.e. could this be a Godaddy cause problem did not change name servers correctly), or is SERVFAIL error only come from company where name servers now point, and it only coincidence that happen at time when change name servers?

Comment: any reason not to tell us exact domain name?

Comment: @dusan.bajic people can obtain personal information through domain name i think (which can be unsafe) but if there is certain information you require from domain name to solve problem please tell me and i update the post with new information

Comment: When did you change name servers?

Comment: @dusan.bajic name servers changed yesterday. WHOIS records show name servers have been changed

Comment: Do you get correct results if you run DIG with +trace option?

Comment: I don't know what "correct" results would be for +trace option, but this is what I get (please note the `xxx` is for the home router ip address). Is this what you expect? `;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 12 bytes from 1XX.1XXX.0.1#53(1XX.1XX.0.1) in 310 ms`

Comment: @dusan.bajic I'm have trouble signing into chat, but I saw your comment about expecting to see IP address. I'm not sure what I expected to see from +trace

Comment: @dusan.bajic I don't have enough reputation to go into chat. Need 20 points.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/60174/servfail?tab=general

Comment: Without the domain name there is noting we can really do to help

Comment: @Iain sorry, i disagree. You (or someone who cares to answer) can tell me steps to follow. But thank you if you do not wish

Comment: Please read http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts especially the NB under _Host names and domain names_.

Comment: @Iain thank you. I read but in absence of domain name steps can be provided to follow. Change name servers is very common, steps to follow if no work probably also very common.

Comment: It really is much more instructive for the clueless if you can work with their data. I was just trying to help you get your problem solved. As it is it will likely be closed before that happens - your problem not mine.

Comment: @Iain I am sorry I make you angry. "Your problem not mine" that is an angry statement, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workstation where you run the dig command is using google public DNS (8.8.8.8), they recently implemented DNSSEC validation.  They return SERVFAIL for domains that fail this validation.  Maybe the domain needs DNSSEC?